# Adding more layers to tensorflow MNIST tutorial makes accuracy drop

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, mnist

Novice to deep learning. 
With MNIST_SOFTMAX.py tutorial from gogoel tensorflow (   https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py), I added two new layers just to see what happen.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
```

Changed code above into

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 256]))
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256, 256]))
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256, 10]))

B1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]))
B2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]))
B3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

Y1 = tf.matmul(x, W1) + B1
Y2 = tf.matmul(Y1, W2) + B2
Y3 = tf.matmul(Y2, W3) + B3
y = Y3
```

it drops accuracy from 0.9188 to 0.1028. can I get some idea of why it drops.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Neural net with hidden layer performing worse than without](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181771/neural-net-with-hidden-layer-performing-worse-than-without)

Comment: Can you post someplace the complete code? I'd like to see how you do training. Stochastic Gradient Descent?

Comment: code in https://github.com/jeongsoopark/MachineLearning/blob/master/mnist_softmax.py 
I only changed layer construction from tensorflow's default MNIST_softmax.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need both [symmetry breaking in the weights](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-apply-symmetry-breaking-to-the-weight-matrices-in-Neural-Networks-but-not-to-the-Biases-during-initilization) and a non-linear activation between layers:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 256], stddev=0.1)) 
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256, 256], stddev=0.1))
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256, 10], stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
y = tf.nn.relu(y)
y = tf.matmul(y, W1) + b1
y = tf.nn.relu(y)
y = tf.matmul(y, W2) + b2
```

That gets accuracy of 0.9653.

Comment: thanks. it makes multi-layered network better than single-layered.

Answer (score 2):

You suffer from the same problem as answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872353/how-to-test-if-my-implementation-of-back-propagation-neural-network-is-correct/41899530#41899530). Essentially, your first hidden layers learn much slower than last. Normally your network should learn the correct weights. Here, however, most likely the weights in the first layer change very little and the error propagates to the next layers. It's so large that the subsequent layers can't possibly correct for it. Check the weights.

Comment: Fixing W, B initialization with random_normal fix it, accuracy = 0.89.  which is still lower than single layered version. But now it seems the vanishing gradient problem as @Lukasz Tracewski you point out. Thanks

Comment: If I am to make a guess that's because your neural network can actually work with random weights by adjusting second and subsequent layers. It's still worse, because it has to deal with first hidden layer "noise", which has difficulty to learn "right" weights.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a non-linear activation function between your layers. Try ReLU.

Comment: `Y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W1) + B1)`
`Y2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Y1, W2) + B2)`
`Y3 = tf.matmul(Y2, W3) + B3`
I tried but it gets 0.1135 accuracy

Comment: Trying plotting your loss function vs. iteration. The loss function should be steadily going down.